# How to filter a view by the value of a global variable (as with the variable module)?

Tags: 7, views

I have a global variable, which is the id of a node representing a current organic group that changes every year. I'd like to have a rules view that filters on members of that group. I've added the right relationships and a filter on the group id of the membership entity. But I can't enter a token or a variable value in the filter dialog. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **contextual filter** and **Provide default value** = PHP Code

[image]

Comment: Better even: With the variable module installed, one can select "Variable" as "Type" in that dialog and then select the required variable.